# RFID Serial Port Time Out When Reading Data

Tags: c++, timeout, serial-port, rfid

thanks for taking the time to look at my issue!

I have a Texas Instruments S4100 RFID scanner. I am attempting to simply read the ID of the tags I swipe over the scanner with a C++ console app. I've been pulling my hair out since this is the first time I've ever worked with serial ports. I found out quite a bit about the issue. I first used the createfile function and then the ReadFile function. I am extremely confident I opened the port correctly as the functions returned true. And when I attempted to open a program I know connects to the device (the demo program that came with the scanner) it says the port is already in use.

Since I could not get data from that method I switched gears and found a .dll from TI itself. The FeComm.dll .. I found online documentation for the .dll here:

http://www.ti.com/rfid/docs/manuals/refmanuals/S6000ProgramLibraryFECOM.pdf

Again I am able to open the port but now I am getting a timeout error even when I swipe the card over the device! In the code below you will see that I manually set the timeout to 8000ms (yes I was pulling at straws haha) but still nothing! Am I missing something really obvious? Perhaps I have to send a command to the device first to "start" it up? The demo program had no source code and I can't find anything that works online. Please offer me a clue as to what is going on! Thanks in advance =)

Here is my main() function:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>

#include "FeCom.h"
#include "FeComDef.h"

#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int iRecProtLen;
    char cPortNr[4];
    char cValue[128];
    char* para = "Timeout";
    char* toValue = "8000";

    _itoa( 1, cPortNr, 10 ); // Convert Integer to Char
    UCHAR cRecBuf[256]; // Buffer size may have to be matched to the receive data

    int handle = FECOM_OpenPort( cPortNr ); // COM:1 is opened
    if( handle < 0 )
    {
        // Code in the event of an error
        cout<<"Error opening the port"<<endl;
    }
    else
    { // Communication via COM:1; if successful, the receive data are located in cRecBuf

        FECOM_SetPortPara(handle, para, toValue);

        if(!FECOM_GetPortPara(handle, para, cValue))
        {
            // code here for displaying the COM parameter
            cout<<"TimeOut Parameter: "<<cValue<<endl;
        }

        iRecProtLen = FECOM_Receive( handle, cRecBuf, 256 );
        // If this is true then the function has thrown an error

        if( iRecProtLen < 0 )
        {
            // Communication erorr or buffer overflow
            if( iRecProtLen == FECOM_ERR_OVL_RECBUF )
            { // Buffer overflow: data in RecBuf are valid receive data
                cout<<"Buffer Overflow"<<endl;
            }

            //cout<<"FECOM ERR OVL RECBUF: "<<FECOM_ERR_OVL_RECBUF<<endl;
        }
        cout<<"IRECTPROTLEN: "<<iRecProtLen<<endl;
        cout<<"Return from Recieve: "<<cRecBuf<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the FeCom.h file.

```
/*-------------------------------------------------------
|                                                       |
|                       FECOM.h                         |
|                                                       |
---------------------------------------------------------


Operation Systems   :   Windows 9x/ME/NT/2000


This file contains the constants, datatypes and function declartions of FECOM.DLL
*/

#ifndef _FECOM_INCLUDE_H
#define _FECOM_INCLUDE_H


#ifdef FECOMDLL
    #define DLL_EXT_FUNC __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall
#else
    #define DLL_EXT_FUNC __declspec(dllimport) __stdcall
#endif



#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif




// #####################################################
// FECOM constants
// #####################################################

// defines for uiFlag in FECOM_EVENT_INIT
#define FECOM_THREAD_ID     1
#define FECOM_WND_HWND      2
#define FECOM_CALLBACK      3
#define FECOM_EVENT         4

// defines for uiUse in FECOM_EVENT_INIT
#define FECOM_CTS_EVENT     1
#define FECOM_DCD_EVENT     2
#define FECOM_DSR_EVENT     3
#define FECOM_RTS_EVENT     4
#define FECOM_DTR_EVENT     5



// #####################################################
// FECOM structures
// #####################################################

// structure for transfering thread-IDs, message-handles or callbacks
typedef struct _FECOM_EVENT_INIT
{
    UINT uiUse;     // defines the event (e.g. FECOM_CTS_EVENT)
    UINT uiMsg;     // message code used with dwThreadID and hwndWnd (e.g. WM_USER_xyz)
    UINT uiFlag;    // specifies the use of the union (e.g. FECOM_WND_HWND)
    union
    {
        DWORD   dwThreadID;         // for thread-ID
        HWND    hwndWnd;            // for window-handle
        void    (*cbFct)(int, int); // for callback-function
        HANDLE  hEvent;             // for event-handle
#ifdef __cplusplus
    };
#else
    }Method;
#endif

} FECOM_EVENT_INIT;



// #####################################################
// FECOM functions
// #####################################################

// miscellaneous functions
void DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_GetDLLVersion( char* cVersion );
int  DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_GetErrorText( int iErrorCode, char* cErrorText );
int  DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_GetLastError( int iPortHnd, int* iErrorCode, char* cErrorText );

// functions for event notification
int  DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_AddEventHandler(int iPortHnd, FECOM_EVENT_INIT* pInit);
int  DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_DelEventHandler(int iPortHnd, FECOM_EVENT_INIT* pInit);

// port functions
int  DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_OpenPort( char* cPortNr );
int  DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_ClosePort( int iPortHnd );
int  DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_GetPortList( int iNext );
int  DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_GetPortPara( int iPortHnd, char* cPara, char* cValue );
int  DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_SetPortPara( int iPortHnd, char* cPara, char* cValue );
int  DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_DoPortCmd( int iPortHnd, char* cCmd, char* cValue );
int  DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_GetPortHnd( char* cPortNr );

// communication function
int  DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_Transceive( int iPortHnd, UCHAR* cSendProt, int iSendLen, UCHAR* cRecProt, int iRecLen );
int  DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_Transmit( int iPortHnd, UCHAR* cSendProt, int iSendLen );
int  DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_Receive( int iPortHnd, UCHAR* cRecProt, int iRecLen );


#undef DLL_EXT_FUNC

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif


// #####################################################
// typedefs of DLL-functions for explicite loading
// #####################################################

// miscellaneous functions
typedef void (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_GET_DLL_VERSION)(char*);
typedef int  (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_GET_ERROR_TEXT)(int, char*);
typedef int  (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_GET_LAST_ERROR)(int, int*, char*);

// functions for event notification
typedef int  (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_ADD_EVENT_HANDLER)(FECOM_EVENT_INIT*);
typedef int  (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_DEL_EVENT_HANDLER)(FECOM_EVENT_INIT*);

// port functions
typedef int  (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_OPEN_PORT)(long);
typedef int  (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_CLOSE_PORT)(int);
typedef int  (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_GET_PORT_LIST)(int);
typedef int  (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_GET_PORT_PARA)(int, char*, char*);
typedef int  (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_SET_PORT_PARA)(int, char*, char*);
typedef int  (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_DO_PORT_CMD)(int, char*, char*);
typedef int  (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_GET_PORT_HND)(char*);

// communication function
typedef int  (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_TRANSCEIVE)(int, UCHAR*, int, UCHAR*, int);
typedef int  (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_TRANSMIT)(int, UCHAR*, int);
typedef int  (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_RECEIVE)(int, UCHAR*, int);

#endif // _FECOM_INCLUDE_H
```

Here is the FeComDef.h file:

```
/*-------------------------------------------------------
|                                                       |
|                       FECOMDef.h                      |
|                                                       |
---------------------------------------------------------


Operation Systems   :   Windows 9x/ME/NT/2000


This file contains the error codes for FECOM.DLL
*/

#ifndef _FECOMDEF_H_
#define _FECOMDEF_H_


// FECOM error codes

// common errors
#define FECOM_ERR_NEWPORT_FAILURE           -1000
#define FECOM_ERR_EMPTY_LIST                -1001
#define FECOM_ERR_POINTER_IS_NULL           -1002
#define FECOM_ERR_NO_MEMORY                 -1003
#define FECOM_ERR_UNSUPPORTED_HARDWARE      -1004   // new in V2.00.00

// error while open the port
#define FECOM_ERR_NO_PORT                   -1010
#define FECOM_ERR_NO_CONNECT                -1011
#define FECOM_ERR_LINK_ID                   -1012
#define FECOM_ERR_PORT_IS_OPEN              -1013   // new in V2.00.00

// handle errors
#define FECOM_ERR_UNKNOWN_HND               -1020
#define FECOM_ERR_HND_IS_NULL               -1021
#define FECOM_ERR_HND_IS_NEGATIVE           -1022
#define FECOM_ERR_NO_HND_FOUND              -1023

// communication errors
#define FECOM_ERR_TIMEOUT                   -1030
#define FECOM_ERR_NO_SENDPROTOCOL           -1031
#define FECOM_ERR_RECEIVE_PROCESS           -1032   // renamed in V2.00.00
#define FECOM_ERR_INIT_COMM_PROCESS         -1033   // new in V2.00.00
#define FECOM_ERR_FLUSH_INPUT_BUFFER        -1034   // new in V2.00.00
#define FECOM_ERR_FLUSH_OUTPUT_BUFFER       -1035   // new in V2.00.00
#define FECOM_ERR_CHANGE_PORT_PARA          -1036   // new in V2.00.00
#define FECOM_ERR_TRANSMIT_PROCESS          -1037   // new in V2.00.00

// parameter errors
#define FECOM_ERR_UNKNOWN_PARAMETER         -1050
#define FECOM_ERR_PARAMETER_OUT_OF_RANGE    -1051
#define FECOM_ERR_ODD_PARAMETERSTRING       -1052
#define FECOM_ERR_PORTNR_OUT_OF_RANGE       -1053
#define FECOM_ERR_UNKNOWN_ERRORCODE         -1054

// receive buffer overflow
#define FECOM_ERR_OVL_RECBUF                -1070


#endif _FECOMDEF_H_
```

If you run the code iRecProtLen = -1030 which according to the documentation is a timeout error. And yes I'm swiping the card over the device while the program runs ;)

I'm not sold on the idea of using these functions. If someone can offer me a solution that they know about I'd be fine with that or if you need more information please ask. I just don't know what the problem is. The port opens but no data read. Really confusing to me. I hope you guys can help!

Comment: First of all, you need to make sure the device is working at all. Open a terminal (e.g. Windows built-in HyperTerminal or free PuTTY) on the port. The docs say the module uses 9600 baud. Swipe the card and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the response! However the device is working properly, the demo program that came with it reads the cards just fine. I'm sorry I should have made that clear in my first post.

Comment: That's good! Still, I'd try connecting via terminal to see for myself that the device does communicate on that port. As another line of thought, the docs mention that the device can boot over serial line. It's possible that your device has no firmware and demo program boots it up before proceeding to work. How about sniffing its communication via Sysinternals PortMon http://live.sysinternals.com/portmon.exe ?

Comment: Ok so I went back and did what you said using PuTTY. My steps were as follows: Open PuTTY -> Clicked the Serial Port Radio Button -> made sure it was on COM1 and 9600 baud rate -> hit "open" -> black terminal box popped up. -> I scanned a card AND... nothing... What does that suggest? Was your thought about the firmware possibly correct then? (Oh and COM1 is for sure the port the device is on =D )... Thank you for all your responses btw! Oh and btw, that portmon.exe didn't work. It gives me "Error 2" when I try to run it. Even as admin.

Comment: For anyone else reading this turns out I was going about this all wrong. I feel like a dummy but I contacted Texas Instruments directly (manufacturer of the device) and they gave me source code to a demo program I can follow. I'm still not 100% there but this question is no longer my issue. Thanks to everyone for looking at this and thanks Atzz for all your suggestions!