# RFID virtual serial port timeout while reading data

Tags: c++, timeout, serial-port, rfid

thanks for taking the time to look at my issue.

I am working with a NFC Encoder device from [ToP Tunniste](http://www.toptunniste.fi) This device creates a virtual serial port. I am trying to read some data into a console application (C++) by swiping RFID tags over the device.

I realize that there is a very similar question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389205/rfid-serial-port-time-out-when-reading-data). I've tried everything suggested in that thread, but without success. Apparently the author of that article found a solution but didn't post it. I can't contact the author directly and when I try to ask him by answering the question my answer gets deleted.

In the code below you can see that I loop over all com ports to detect the active ones. When a port is detected, I try to open it, which succeeds. But then if I try to read from the device, I always get a "-1030 Timeout when reading from the port"-error, although I am swiping a tag over the device.

When I use the device with the sample software, I am able to read from/write to a RFID tag. So I must be missing something here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include "fecom.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    int Err;
    char cPortNr[4];
    int iRecProtLen;
    UCHAR cRecBuf[256];
    int handle;

    //loop through ports 1 to 256 to detect devices.
    for(int iPortNr=1; iPortNr<257; ++iPortNr)
    {
        if(0 == FECOM_DetectPort( iPortNr ))
        {
        std::cout << "Detected port: " << iPortNr << std::endl;

        itoa( iPortNr, cPortNr, 10 ); // Convert Integer to Char

        handle = FECOM_OpenPort( cPortNr ); // COM:cPortNr should be opened
        if( handle < 0 )
        {
            // code here for error condition
            std::cout << "Error opening port: COM:" << cPortNr << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {   // Communication through COM:cPortNr, if successful received data are in RecBuf
            // code here for communication or other
            std::cout << "Successfully connected to port COM:" << cPortNr << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Press enter to read from COM:" << cPortNr << " (5s)" << std::endl;
            std::cin.get();
            Err = FECOM_SetPortPara(handle,"Timeout","5000");
            Err = FECOM_SetPortPara(handle,"CharTimeout","5000");

            iRecProtLen = FECOM_Receive( handle, cRecBuf, 256 );
            if( iRecProtLen < 0 )
            {
                // Communication error or buffer overflow
                if( iRecProtLen == FECOM_ERR_OVL_RECBUF )
                { // Buffer overflow: Data in RecBuf are valid receive data
                    std::cout << "Buffer overflow error" << std::endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    char cErrorText[256];
                    FECOM_GetErrorText(iRecProtLen, cErrorText);
                    std::cout << "Error: " << iRecProtLen << " " << cErrorText << std::endl;
                    std::cout << std::endl;
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                std::cout << "Data received: " << cRecBuf << std::endl;
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
            Err = FECOM_ClosePort(handle);
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Program terminated. Press enter to close." <<std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

iRecProtLen = -1030

this is the fecom.h file:

```
/*-------------------------------------------------------
|                                                       |
|                       fecom.h                         |
|                                                       |
---------------------------------------------------------

Copyright  2000-2010    FEIG ELECTRONIC GmbH, All Rights Reserved.
                        Lange Strasse 4
                        D-35781 Weilburg
                        Federal Republic of Germany
                        phone    : +49 6471 31090
                        fax      : +49 6471 310999
                        e-mail   : obid-support@feig.de
                        Internet : http://www.feig.de

Author              :   Markus Hultsch

Version             :   Windows:        02.08.12 / 25.03.2010 / M. Hultsch
Version             :   Linux:          02.08.10 / 18.08.2009 / M. Sahm
Version             :   Windows CE:     02.08.11 / 22.03.2010 / M. Hultsch

Operation Systems   :   Windows 2000/XP/Vista/7
                    Linux
                    Windows CE


This file contains the constants, datatypes and function declartions of FECOM library
*/

#ifndef _FECOM_INCLUDE_H
#define _FECOM_INCLUDE_H


#if defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(__BORLANDC__)
#ifdef FECOMDLL
    #define DLL_EXT_FUNC __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall
#else
    #define DLL_EXT_FUNC __declspec(dllimport) __stdcall
#endif

#ifndef CALLBACK
    #define CALLBACK __stdcall
#endif
#else
#define DLL_EXT_FUNC
#define CALLBACK
#endif


// type defines
#ifdef __GNUC__
#ifndef __int64
    #define __int64 long long
#endif
#endif

#ifndef UCHAR
#define UCHAR unsigned char
#endif

#ifndef UINT
#define UINT unsigned int
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
#endif




// #####################################################
// FECOM constants
// #####################################################

// FECOM error codes

// common errors
#define FECOM_ERR_NEWPORT_FAILURE           -1000
#define FECOM_ERR_EMPTY_LIST                -1001
#define FECOM_ERR_POINTER_IS_NULL           -1002
#define FECOM_ERR_NO_MEMORY                 -1003
#define FECOM_ERR_UNSUPPORTED_HARDWARE      -1004
#define FECOM_ERR_PORT_NOT_FOUND            -1005
#define FECOM_ERR_UNSUPPORTED               -1006

// error while open the port
#define FECOM_ERR_NO_PORT                   -1010
#define FECOM_ERR_NO_CONNECT                -1011
#define FECOM_ERR_LINK_ID                   -1012
#define FECOM_ERR_PORT_IS_OPEN              -1013

// handle errors
#define FECOM_ERR_UNKNOWN_HND               -1020
#define FECOM_ERR_HND_IS_NULL               -1021
#define FECOM_ERR_HND_IS_NEGATIVE           -1022
#define FECOM_ERR_NO_HND_FOUND              -1023

// communication errors
#define FECOM_ERR_TIMEOUT                   -1030
#define FECOM_ERR_NO_SENDPROTOCOL           -1031
#define FECOM_ERR_RECEIVE_PROCESS           -1032
#define FECOM_ERR_INIT_COMM_PROCESS         -1033
#define FECOM_ERR_FLUSH_INPUT_BUFFER        -1034
#define FECOM_ERR_FLUSH_OUTPUT_BUFFER       -1035
#define FECOM_ERR_CHANGE_PORT_PARA          -1036
#define FECOM_ERR_TRANSMIT_PROCESS          -1037
#define FECOM_ERR_RECEIVE_NOISE_DATA        -1038
#define FECOM_ERR_PORT_IS_BUSY              -1039
#define FECOM_ERR_READ_PORT_PARA            -1040

// parameter errors
#define FECOM_ERR_UNKNOWN_PARAMETER         -1050
#define FECOM_ERR_PARAMETER_OUT_OF_RANGE    -1051
#define FECOM_ERR_ODD_PARAMETERSTRING       -1052
#define FECOM_ERR_PORTNR_OUT_OF_RANGE       -1053
#define FECOM_ERR_UNKNOWN_ERRORCODE         -1054

// receive buffer overflow
#define FECOM_ERR_OVL_RECBUF                -1070



// constants for dynamic load of library

// miscellaneous functions
#define FECOM_GET_DLL_VERSION           1000
#define FECOM_GET_ERROR_TEXT            1001
#define FECOM_GET_LAST_ERROR            1002
#define FECOM_DETECT_PORT               1003

// functions for event notification
#define FECOM_ADD_EVENT_HANDLER         1010
#define FECOM_DEL_EVENT_HANDLER         1011

// port functions
#define FECOM_OPEN_PORT                 1020
#define FECOM_CLOSE_PORT                1021
#define FECOM_GET_PORT_LIST             1022
#define FECOM_GET_PORT_PARA             1023
#define FECOM_SET_PORT_PARA             1024
#define FECOM_DO_PORT_CMD               1025
#define FECOM_GET_PORT_HND              1026

// communication function
#define FECOM_TRANSCEIVE                1030
#define FECOM_TRANSMIT                  1031
#define FECOM_RECEIVE                   1032



// constants for structure _FECOM_EVENT_INIT

// defines for uiFlag in FECOM_EVENT_INIT
#define FECOM_THREAD_ID     1
#define FECOM_WND_HWND      2
#define FECOM_CALLBACK      3
#define FECOM_EVENT         4

// defines for uiUse in FECOM_EVENT_INIT
#define FECOM_CTS_EVENT              1
#define FECOM_DCD_EVENT              2
#define FECOM_DSR_EVENT              3
#define FECOM_RTS_EVENT              4
#define FECOM_DTR_EVENT              5

#define FECOM_PORT_CLOSED_EVENT     20  // only for Windows CE (customized   versions)
#define FECOM_PORT_REOPEN_EVENT     21  // only for Windows CE (customized versions)



// #####################################################
// FECOM structures
// #####################################################

// structure for transfering thread-IDs, message-handles or callbacks
typedef struct _FECOM_EVENT_INIT
{
UINT uiUse;     // defines the event (e.g. FECOM_CTS_EVENT)
UINT uiMsg;     // message code used with dwThreadID and hwndWnd (e.g. WM_USER_xyz)
UINT uiFlag;    // specifies the use of the union (e.g. FECOM_WND_HWND)
union
{
//#if defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(__BORLANDC__)
#if defined(__BORLANDC__)
    DWORD   dwThreadID;         // for thread-ID
    HWND    hwndWnd;            // for window-handle
    HANDLE  hEvent;             // for event-handle
#endif
    void    (*cbFct)(int, int); // for callback-function
#ifdef __cplusplus
};
#else
}Method;
#endif

} FECOM_EVENT_INIT;



// #####################################################
// FECOM functions
// #####################################################

// miscellaneous functions
void DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_GetDLLVersion( char* cVersion );
int  DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_GetErrorText( int iErrorCode, char* cErrorText );
int  DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_GetLastError( int iPortHnd, int* iErrorCode, char* cErrorText     );
int  DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_DetectPort( int iPortNr );

// functions for event notification
int  DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_AddEventHandler(int iPortHnd, FECOM_EVENT_INIT* pInit);
int  DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_DelEventHandler(int iPortHnd, FECOM_EVENT_INIT* pInit);

// port functions
int  DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_OpenPort( char* cPortNr );
int  DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_ClosePort( int iPortHnd );
int  DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_GetPortList( int iNext );
int  DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_GetPortPara( int iPortHnd, char* cPara, char* cValue );
int  DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_SetPortPara( int iPortHnd, char* cPara, char* cValue );
int  DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_DoPortCmd( int iPortHnd, char* cCmd, char* cValue );
int  DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_GetPortHnd( char* cPortNr );

// communication function
int  DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_Transceive( int iPortHnd, UCHAR* cSendProt, int iSendLen,     UCHAR* cRecProt, int iRecLen );
int  DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_Transmit( int iPortHnd, UCHAR* cSendProt, int iSendLen );
int  DLL_EXT_FUNC FECOM_Receive( int iPortHnd, UCHAR* cRecProt, int iRecLen );


#undef DLL_EXT_FUNC

#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
#endif


// #####################################################
// typedefs of library functions for explicite loading
// #####################################################

// miscellaneous functions
typedef void (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_GET_DLL_VERSION)(char*);
typedef int  (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_GET_ERROR_TEXT)(int, char*);
typedef int  (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_GET_LAST_ERROR)(int, int*, char*);
typedef int  (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_DETECT_PORT)(int);

// functions for event notification
typedef int  (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_ADD_EVENT_HANDLER)(int, FECOM_EVENT_INIT*);
typedef int  (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_DEL_EVENT_HANDLER)(int, FECOM_EVENT_INIT*);

// port functions
typedef int  (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_OPEN_PORT)(char*);
typedef int  (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_CLOSE_PORT)(int);
typedef int  (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_GET_PORT_LIST)(int);
typedef int  (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_GET_PORT_PARA)(int, char*, char*);
typedef int  (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_SET_PORT_PARA)(int, char*, char*);
typedef int  (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_DO_PORT_CMD)(int, char*, char*);
typedef int  (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_GET_PORT_HND)(char*);

// communication function
typedef int  (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_TRANSCEIVE)(int, UCHAR*, int, UCHAR*, int);
typedef int  (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_TRANSMIT)(int, UCHAR*, int);
typedef int  (CALLBACK* LPFN_FECOM_RECEIVE)(int, UCHAR*, int);

#endif // _FECOM_INCLUDE_H
```

Comment: Yes, on Windows 7. Should have made that clear in the original post, sorry.

Comment: Could you modify the program such that you can pass it the actual COM port you wish to talk to, instead of iterating over all of them and see if that helps?

Comment: That is what I tried first. When that failed, I decided to do it like this. The device is on COM port 2. When I loop over all of them, the program detects COM1 and COM2. COM1 fails, as there's no reader device connected, but COM2 shouldn't fail.

Comment: Are you tied to Windows or can you try this on Linux?

Comment: I can try to install it on linux, but the task description says it should eventually work on Windows. (I'm doing my practical training) I have an appointment with a fellow student tomorrow, maybe he has an idea. If I find a solution, I'll post it here. Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I need to use a different protocol for communicating with the port.

Although I have to use FECOM to open/close a port, I can't use it for read/write operations on the device. To do that, I have to use FEISC, a different protocol/library.

As soon as I have some working code, I'll put it on here, but I think we can consider this issue solved.

Thanks anyway to everyone who took a look at this.